# Is it possible for a power series to be conditionally convergent at two different points?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series, conditional-convergence

Like I stated in the title, I was just wondering if it's possible for a power series to be conditionally convergent at two different points. Are there any examples of power series that fit this criteria?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: That's an interesting question. What have you tried so far?

Comment: For what it's worth, I originally posted and then deleted a comment.  I misinterpreted the query to mean that you were wondering if a conditionally convergent power sequence at one fixed point in the domain of the function could simultaneously have two accumulation points.  Instead, you are asking whether two distinct points in the domain of the function can each produce a conditionally convergent series.

Answer (score 8):

Try $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{n}$$ at $x=1$ and $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

If the argument is complex, the answer is yes.  For example $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k}$ has a radius of convergence $r=1$ and diverges for $z=1$, but converges for $z=-1$ and $z=\pm i$.

Wild guess: it converges for all points on the unit circle, except $z=1$

Comment: Your "wild guess" is correct, by Dirichlet's test.

Comment: @Robert Israel  Reference to how it is used here?  I have a straightforward proof for a dense subset of points on the unit circle, but not all.

Comment: [Dirichlet's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test).  $1/k$ decreases to $0$, $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^N z^n\right| = \left|\dfrac{z^{N+1}-1}{z-1}\right| \le \dfrac{2}{|z-1|}$$ is bounded for each $z \ne 1$ in the unit circle.

Comment: @RobertIsrael  Thank you!