# It is possible that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$ converges conditionally on $x = R$ and on $x = −R$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions, power-series

Prove/Disprove: Let $0 \le R \le  \infty$ be the radii of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$. Then, it is possible that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nx^n$ converges conditionally on $x = R$ and on $x = −R$.

I am trying to find a series that does not converges absolutely, but do converges conditionally, and I have tried:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^n}{n}$, it does not converges absolutely, and it is converges for $x=1$, but not for $x=-1$.

I also tried $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n}$ which converges for $x=-1$ but not for $x=1$.

Will appreciate your help :)

Thanks!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4085054/42969

Comment: If you replace $x^n$ with $x^{2n}$, your first example will work (the even exponent prevents any cancellation from negatives).

Comment: Thank you for that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $a_n=0$ for $n$ odd and $a_n=\frac {(-1)^{n/2}} n$ for $n$ even.

Comment: Thank you Kavi!